# How do I get started with Juju?

Tags: cloud, juju

I want to mess with [Ubuntu Juju](http://juju.ubuntu.com), how do I get started?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- [Getting Started Tutorial](https://jujucharms.com/get-started)
- [Full Documentation](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started)

Getting started with a Amazon [AWS account](http://aws.amazon.com/) is very simple, or there is also directions to deploy test instances to local lxc containers, a third more in-depth option is to setup a MAAS (Metal As A Service) first as described also in the docs.

The [Getting Started](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/config-aws) section tells you how to install it and where to input your AWS access-key and secret-key. If you choose the easier AWS route, which go in your `~/.juju/environments.yaml` file, if not those are not required but the other keys mentioned are.

After that, start with [the tutorial](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/getting-started) to deploy a sample Wordpress instance and it will be fully up and running in a matter of minutes if your successful.