# How do I adjust the instance size that Juju uses?

Tags: amazon-ec2, juju

I've fired up some of the [example instances](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52012/how-do-i-get-started-with-ensemble) of Wordpress and MySQL with Juju. A coworker has told me that the default instance size is "small". I'd like to be able to scale this to different sizes on Amazon EC2.

How can I adjust this, is this something defined in a formula or is it an argument I can pass Juju on the command line?

Let's say for example I wanted to deploy wordpress on "large" amazon instances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this section](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/constraints.html) of the documentation you need to define the
`instance-type` as part of a machine constraint:

> Deploy MySQL on a machine with at least 32GiB of RAM, and at least 8
>   ECU of CPU power (architecture will be inherited from the environment,
>   or default to amd64):
>
> ```
> juju deploy --constraints "cpu-cores=8 mem=32G" mysql
> ```
>
> Deploy to t1.micros on AWS:
>
> ```
> juju bootstrap --constraints "cpu-power=0 mem=512M"
> ```
>
> Launch all future "mysql" machines with at least 8GiB of RAM and 4
>   ECU:
>
> ```
> juju set-constraints --service mysql mem=8G cpu-cores=4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is one caveat about setting this on the environment namely that if your using an image which needs a 64-bit image, you'll need to [specify the ami directly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84333/how-do-i-use-a-specific-ami-for-juju-instances) with `default-instance-id`.

We're currently working on a more generic resource constraint implementation which will be significantly more flexible and cross provider.