# How do I use a specific AMI for juju instances?

Tags: juju

I would like to use another AMI with juju instead of the default AMI, where do I specify this?

Answer (score 5):

This used to be supported in `~/.juju/environments.yaml` as `default-image-id` in older versions of Juju but is currently unimplemented in Juju 2.x.

According to this thread it just needs to be implemented:

- https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/juju/2013-April/002389.html

Comment: This answer is out-of-date now and refers to the Python version of juju, which is not supported anymore. juju-core (the Go version) supports an "instance-type" constraint (run `juju help constraints` for more info) to select e.g. "m1.small", but specifying an AMI to use is not supported.

Answer (score -1):

If the image id is absolutely necessary for you, then this how you can get it working in precise.

Create a directory of your choice. cd into it and run:

```
bzr branch lp:juju/0.5
```

However before you can run from source, you need to make sure you have the dependencies installed.

```
sudo apt-get install python-zookeeper python-virtualenv python-yaml
```

Next cd into the 0.5 directory and run `bzr revert -r479`

Now run `python setup.py develop` inside the directory. Juju works great :)