# Where can I find juju tutorials?

Tags: server, juju

Is there any good and easy-to-understand Juju tutorial from beginner? I know a bit about virtualization using qemu or oracle vm virtualbox and looking forward to enhance my skill in the cloud infrastructure.

Most of the tutorial are way too advance for me. Usually started without explanation on the Juju concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several starting points. Some were pointed out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52012/how-do-i-get-started-with-juju).

There are also a few nice instructional videos on Youtube. For example [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ft-2Sd4JYWY)
or even [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxMhKbDSbOw), while the second is about 
 Ensemble, but the syntax is quite similar.

There is also a webinar here:

- http://www.brighttalk.com/webcast/6793/39309